# Variance of mean estimator with variable sample size

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, parameter-estimation

I'm looking at a random variable that takes vectors $\newcommand{\vv}{\mathbf{v}} \vv_1, \dotsc, \vv_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and calculates their average, after applying "blankout" noise to them. So we have independent Bernoulli random variables $\xi_1, \dotsc, \xi_n$ with parameters $p(\xi_i = 1) = p_i$. I multiply the $\newcommand{\vv}{\mathbf{v}} \vv_i$ by the $\xi_i$ and take the average of the ones that remain:

$$\newcommand{\vv}{\mathbf{v}} \frac{\xi_1 \vv_1 + \dotsb + \xi_n \vv_n}{\xi_1 + \dotsb + \xi_n}.$$

(I could define it to be zero in case all $\xi_i = 0$.)

What is the variance of such a thing? If you like we can take all $p_i$ equal to simplify the analysis.

I asked about the mean [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812757/taking-the-average-after-randomly-knocking-out-members).

Comment: what do you mean by the variance of a random vector? you mean the covariance matrix?

Comment: @leonbloy Yes.-------

Comment: Do you mean that $v_i$s are some given vectors?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Yes.